# SwiftUI List add empty space at the bottom

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I would like to allow the `SwiftUI List` to scroll all the way up to the place where header of the last `Section` will be at the top of the `List` view. I know that I could use `GeometryReader` to calculate height of the `List` and by knowing the `height` of each list cell I could calculate how much empty space I should add at the bottom of the list to push it up. The problem is that if cells will for example expand or have flexible size, then it won't work. I was wondering if there is maybe some modifier that I don't know about or some more "flexible" way to do that?

This is the code for the `List`

```
import SwiftUI

struct ListSections: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section(header: Text("Header 1")) {
                ForEach((0...10), id: \.self) { index in
                    Text("item \(index)")
                }
            }
            
            Section(header: Text("Header 2")) {
                ForEach((0...12), id: \.self) { index in
                    Text("item \(index)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On the image below you can see on the left how far I can scroll by default and on the right how far I would like to be able to scroll.

[image]

Comment: and you want header to be floating, even if it’s data is all scrolled all up?Or you want header1 also to move up?

Comment: You could try a `Spacer().frame(height: 400)` underneath the last section. But, there is an extra line that I can't figure out how to remove.

Comment: @TusharSharma I like "sticky" headers so I would like Header 2 to push up Header 1 (like on the right screenshot) and Header 2 to stick to the top.

Comment: @aheze by doing this you will add fixed spacing that would be there even if I will have more elements that you can fit in the screen and I want it to be there only if there is not enough elements to push last section header to the top of the view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two options here:
**Option 1 (preferred way)**
Just adding a bottom padding to the last Section:

```
struct ListSections: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section(header: Text("Header 1")) {
                ForEach((0...10), id: \.self) { index in
                    Text("item \(index)")
                }
            }

            Section(header: Text("Header 2")) {
                ForEach((0...12), id: \.self) { index in
                    Text("item \(index)")
                }
            }
            .padding(.bottom, 300)
        }
    }
}
```

**Option 2:**
Adding a View after the last section inside your List will do the trick. For instance I used a Color view.

Your code should look like:

```
struct ListSections: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section(header: Text("Header 1")) {
                ForEach((0...10), id: \.self) { index in
                    Text("item \(index)")
                }
            }
            
            Section(header: Text("Header 2")) {
                ForEach((0...12), id: \.self) { index in
                    Text("item \(index)")
                }
            }
            
            Color(.clear)
               .frame(height: 300)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Option 2 crashes in device running iOS 13. Better use  Rectangle()
                    .frame(height: 300)

Comment: It looks like option 1 adds the padding to all children rows instead of the container section.

Comment: can add `.listRowBackground(Color.clear)` if you see white background for option 2

Answer (score 3):

In iOS 15, the `safeAreaPadding(_:)` allows you to add `contentsInsets` to the edges of the view. To implement this in your code, you can follow these steps:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ListSections: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section(header: Text("Header 1")) {
                ForEach((0...10), id: \.self) { index in
                    Text("item \(index)")
                }
            }

            Section(header: Text("Header 2")) {
                ForEach((0...12), id: \.self) { index in
                    Text("item \(index)")
                }
            }
        }
        .safeAreaPadding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 100, trailing: 0))
    }
}
```

Comment: a little mistake there, as per Apple information, it is available from iOS 17
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/safeareapadding(_:)-5lh9p?changes=_6